# Can I use 2 WANs on DD-WRT?

Tags: routing, dd-wrt

I bought TL-WR1043ND and flashed it with DD-WRT. Now Im wondering if it's possible to use physical WAN port and wireless client WAN for internet usage and at the same time broadcast SSID for wired and wireless clients to share files?

Here's a quick mockup in Paint:
[Network map made in paint http://hostogo.com/image-1EF8_4E70E961.jpg](http://hostogo.com/image-1EF8_4E70E961.jpg)

Comment: Please explain why or in in what way does this one client *need* to access the Internet specifically through router 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, you can't use the wifi as AP and client at the same time, but you can use one usb wifi as client for 2nd WAN link.